# Jasmine test case error unexpected request

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have service in my controller,

```
$scope.doLogin=function(email, password) { 

    $http.post("oauth/token",  "grant_type=password&username=test@test.com&password=123456", {
      headers: {
         'Authorization': "BASIC",
         'Content-Type': "application/json"
      }
      }).success(function(data, status) {

      }).error(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
   })

}
```

this is my testcase

```
describe ('when populate method is called', function () {
    it ('should returns user data', function () {

         var p = $scope.doLogin('associate11@test.com', '123456');

         $httpBackend.whenPOST("/oauth/token"); 

         $httpBackend.flush();

         p.then(function(response) {
             expect(response.data).toBeDefined();
         });
    });
});
```

The error I get is:

Error: Unexpected request: POST https://test/oauth/token
 No more request expected